# Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n-1\over{{(n^3+n+2)}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am doing some Analysis I exercises but am stuck with trying to find convergence or divergence for this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n-1\over{{(n^3+n+2)}}}$$

What the teacher has shown in class is that given a series, you can calculate a partial sum, $S(n)$. If the limit exists, the series is convergent.

We were given some examples, like $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{{(2^k)}}}$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{{{(2^k)}}}$$ which were relatively easy to solve by multiplying $S(n)$ and the summation by numbers and doing the proper manipulations until you got $S(n) =$ to something and you can check the limit of that something, but I don't see where to start with such a strategy here. Could someone give me a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know an equivalent of you summand?

Comment: Note that

$${n-1\over{{n^3+n+2}}}\le{n\over{{n^3}}}=\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: So the way to prove this is ignoring the summatory and just finding some expression that I know converges and is bigger than the one in the summatory?

Comment: @ManuelDelRíoRodríguez Exactly, this is the [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test), the simplest criterion for positive series

Comment: Small nitpick, but I think you meant to type $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n}$ instead of $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in most of cases, we have no way to compute the partial sum and get a closed form. So we have to use some tests to see if the series is convergent or divergent. One of very useful test is the comparison test. Suppose $a_n\ge0, b_n\ge0$, and $a_n\le b_n$, if $\sum b_n$ is convergent, then $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

For your case, we have

$$n-1\le n,~~~~\frac{1}{n^3+n+2}\le \frac1{n^3}$$

therefore

$$0\le a_n=\frac{n-1}{n^3+n+2}\le\frac n{n^3}=\frac1{n^2}=b_n$$

Now, by comparison test, since $\sum b_n=\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent, hence $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important result that states that if we have sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=L, $$ for $L>0$ finite and $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ does. In our case tour sequence behaves as $1/n^2$ whose series converges.

Comment: This is known as limit comparison test, note that is can be also used when $L=0$ (convergent case) and when $L=\infty$ (divergent case).

Comment: Note that $a_n$ terms should ultimately be positive (or of constant sign) for the theorem to apply (counter example $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$ divergent while $b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ convergent series).

Answer (score 0):

We can use limit comparision test here

choose $a_n=\frac{n-1}{n^3+n+2}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$

So here

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n-1}{n^3+n+2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
$$\Rightarrow L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3(1-\frac{1}{n})}{n^3(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3})}$$
$$\Rightarrow L=1$$
As $L=1\neq 0,\neq \infty$
So by limit comparision test $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ will have same nature of convergence or divergence .
$\sum b_n=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent by p-series test as here $p=2>1$
Hence given series is convergent